# Using/Parsing curl in Delphi XE10.1

Tags: rest, delphi, curl, indy10, delphi-10.1-berlin

I have this curl sequence, that works in MS Windows and I am trying to use the equivalence with Indy in Delphi XE 10.1 Berlin.

The curl code is this:

```
curl -k "https://fakeweb.com/options" --data-binary "{\"name\":\"Name of the Client\",\"email\":\"fake@gmail.com\"}"
```

I have tried the following code, but it does not work

```
procedure TForm2.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
const
  COMI = Char(34);
var
  data: string;
  DataToSend : TStringStream;
  IdHTTP: TIdHTTP;
  Answer: string;
begin
  try
    data := '{\' + COMI  + 'name\' + COMI  + ':\' + COMI  + 'Name of the Client\' + COMI  +
          ',\' + COMI  + 'email\' + COMI  + ':\' + COMI   + 'fake@gmail.com\' + COMI  + '}' ;

    DataToSend := TStringStream.Create(data);

    IdHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(Application);

    IdHTTP.Request.Accept := 'application/json, text/plain; q=0.9, text/html;q=0.8,';
    IdHTTP.Request.ContentType := 'application/json, text/plain; q=0.9, text/html;q=0.8,';

    Answer := IdHTTP.Post('https://fakeweb.com/options', DataToSend);    //its not the real URL

    ShowMessage(Answer);
  except on E: Exception do
    ShowMessage('Error: '+E.ToString);
  end;
end;
```

Always I get the same messagge : HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Srever Error.
Can someone helps me?

Thank you.

Comment: Send the payload without the backslashes. They are only escape characters for curl.

Comment: @mjn42 thanks for answer but I have tried without the backslashes too, and the same error. The code is the last test.

Comment: Unrelated to what you're asking but you don't seem to free `DataToSend`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are three problems with your code:

1. You are corrupting your JSON string, which may cause the HTTP error.  The slash character is not used as an escape sequence in Delphi string literals (it is not even an escape sequence in curl itself, either. It is the command-line processor that requires it), so you are posting actual slash characters that do not belong in your JSON data at all.  Also, while not technically wrong, your `COMI` constant is unnecessary, since Delphi strings use `'` for quoting, so you can safely use `"` as-is in the string data.
2. You are setting the `TIdHTTP.Request.ContentType` property to an invalid value, which may also cause the HTTP error.
3. You are leaking the objects you are creating, if this code is run on Windows or OSX (well, the `TIdHTTP` object is not "leaked" exactly, but it is not destroyed until the app exits). There is no leaking if the code is run on iOS or Android.

Try this instead:

```
procedure TForm2.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  data: string;
  DataToSend : TStringStream;
  IdHTTP: TIdHTTP;
  Answer: string;
begin
  try
    data := '{"name":"Name of the Client","email":"fake@gmail.com"}';
    DataToSend := TStringStream.Create(data, TEncoding.UTF8);
    try
      IdHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
      try
        IdHTTP.Request.Accept := 'application/json, text/plain;q=0.9, text/html;q=0.8';
        IdHTTP.Request.ContentType := 'application/json';
        Answer := IdHTTP.Post('https://fakeweb.com/options', DataToSend);    
      finally
        IdHTTP.Free;
      end;
    finally
      DataToSend.Free;
    end;
    ShowMessage(Answer);
  except
    on E: Exception do
      ShowMessage('Error: '+E.ToString);
  end;
end;
```